# PHP Retrieve array values from foreach loop and pass individual values to function

Tags: php, codeigniter, return-value

I have a function which contains a foreach loop that loops through an array and brings back each value using $row['COLORS'].  The goal is to pass the value into a function that is called.  Here is my problem.  I cannot use the 'return' to pass the value.  Due to the foreach loop, I cannot use a return in order to keep the loop going.  Below code works for 1 record only.

```
function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();

   $this->myColors = $this->getColors();
}  

public function getColors() {
   sql = $this->buildSQL();
   $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

   foreach ($query as $row) {
     $theColor = $row['COLOR'];
     return $theColor;
  }
}
```

I need to do the same for each of the colors in the array, not just one value.  I have tried passing the value to another function with a return but it doesn't return where I need it in the __construct.

```
...
foreach ($query as $row) {
   $theColor = $row['COLOR'];
   $this->returnColor($passColor);
}
public function returnColor($passColor) {
    return $passColor;
}
```

I also tried a function with a switch statement (which is not a viable solution due to hundreds of values) but again the return does not work in this situation.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: take the return out of the loop

Comment: Do you need to return an array of these values? If so, then collect them and make the return out of the loop statement. In the other case you will receive one value every time.

Comment: The return was taken out of loop but nothing happened.  Also I do not need to collect the values.  I just need to retrieve each value at a time.  The issue maybe how to pass the value to the __constructor.

Comment: Thank you to those who responded.  Any more thoughts . . . anyone?